Permission inconsistency for Settings.canDrawOverlays on incoming/ongoing calls in Android 14 release build
fellow Android developers,
I'm facing a perplexing issue with overlay permissions during phone state changes on Android 14. My application's goal is to display an overlay view when a phone call is incoming or ongoing. To achieve this, I've set up a BroadcastReceiver to listen for phone state changes, checking for overlay permissions within the receiver.
Here's how I've implemented it:
Manifest declarations:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<!-- Other permissions -->

<receiver android:name="com.hasys.hairzzang.receiver.CallReceiver" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

CallReceiver implementation:
class CallReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(context)) return
        // Logic to display overlay view
    }
}

In both IDE-direct builds and debug APKs, when overlay permission is granted, the permission check proceeds without any issues. However, in release APKs, despite the permission being granted, Settings.canDrawOverlays returns false during incoming or ongoing calls. Intriguingly, this permission seems to be temporarily revoked during calls, as observed in the app's permission settings. It reverts back to granted once the call ends.
I've confirmed this behavior exclusively on Android 14. ProGuard has been disabled for the release builds, yet the issue persists.
Could anyone shed some light on what might be causing this permission inconsistency during phone calls in release builds? Any guidance or workaround suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!
